# Kmeans applied to positively skewed variables

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, k-means, skewness

The situation I'm facing is relative to a dataset of customers where I'm trying to aggregate 7 clusters of them leveraging on variables related to the type of financial product utilized with a bank.

For each type of product I have two type of variable, one related to the total volume of money generated with that product (so if credit card, the total amount of transaction generated with the card), and the other to the N of operations related to that product ( N of transaction in credit card case). So a dataset type would be:

```
ID  credit_card_volumes credit_card_trans   loan_volume loan_tran   revolving_volume    revolving_tran
1   5000    37  10000   2   500 21
2   3000    66  0   0   0   0
3   6000    55  2000    1   0   0
```

Now, as this is a retail related bank, most of customers do not have a constant relation with the financial entity, so the majority of customers have a "one spot" purchase of debt/loan product, and zero usage of the cards, or on the contrary a few use the cards costantly, while the majority no, with few or no purchase of loan/debts.

Below an example of the typical distribution of these variables

[image: variables distribution]

To summarize, being a dataset of 600K customers, the variables are highly positive skewed, with few customers with positive values, and the majority with "0" values

I have followed this methodology into trying to aggregate the clusters:

**Methodology**

1. as the kmeans work with normally distributed data I have  log transformed the original variable
2. then, I have standardized the log version of the variables to reduct impact of the variable variances
3. then, I have applied a PCA analysis to reduce the N of original variables to a few of them, selecting the one with an engine values >1
4. then, on these PCA, I have run a kmean algorith with max N of cluster equal to 10

the **results** are the following :

[image: cluster result]

A huge big cluster including more than 90% of the observations and the remaining with a few of obs. Of curse, this kind of solution is not optimal, but I was expecting that by using the log transformation and the subsequent standardization of the variables the positive skewness would have not affected the clustering algorithm, as indeed seems the case.

Now, just for mentioning it, I have tried too to run

a. A Factor analysis on the initial dataset 
b. Selected the three Factors with an engine values greater than 1
c. Run the kmeans with these three Factor

But the result is pretty more the same, one big cluster and lot of them with few obs

So I suppose that no one of the two utilized methodolgies have helped in managing the high skeweness of the variables distributions, and the consequence they have on the kmeans algorithm.

So the question is:

**Has anyone managed a clustering task with variable positively skewed like per my case, and then be able to get well balanced clusters in terms of obs ? Or better defined, does anyone know how to manipulate so highly skewed variables in order to use them within a Kmeans algorithm?**

I haven't used hierarchical methods as the dataset is too big and then SAS crash for the workload.

**UPDATE 17/11/2017** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I did a little change to the analysis and jumped the step regarding the standaridzation of the log version of the variables...And the result is the following

[image]

Except for three cluster composed by a few obs (pretty sure are outliers), the new clusters get more obs than the first tentative where just one was getting more than 90% of the obs. Also, I have tried different N of cluster in the kmeans , and the N=9 seems the best solution in terms of CCC.

However, I was expecting that the standardization of the log variables would have positively affected the algorithm, as it is a matter of fact that the variables have different variances, as some product are more skewed than others in terms of spend.

On the contrary, it seems the standardization let the algorith aggregate majority of obs in one cluster.

**Question: Could anyone explain why the standardization in this particular situation is making all the obs aggregating in one big clusters? I'm doing wrong in not standardizing the log version of the variables ?**

Comment: First, why do clusters, if they exist, have to be about "balanced" groups? There are many examples in reality when one huge cluster dominates; then one might eventually decide that the small clusters are just noise in the sample. Second, while it is all right with the idea to transform data to more symmetric shape, still, k-means does not assume a symmetric distribution; it assumes/prefers convex clusters with appox. same variances, and that is all.

Comment: Hierarhical clusering is not used for many thousands of objects not only because of ram memory, but, more important, because it is greedy algorithm.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns . I see your point but from a business perspective It is not an actionable cluster. Furthermore, I suspect it is caused by the high skeweness of the variables. There is some process you can suggest in trying an alternative method with these kind of variables?

Comment: Davide, I did not say that you did wrong. It is often, if not ever, a sane idea to transform the overall very skew distribution to more symmetric before clustering, provided that data values were recorded with sufficient precision. I just think that there are no any expressed worthy clusters in your data.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for precious opinion.  tried a change in the analysis and jumped the phase of the standardization of the log version of the variables, keeping all the other steps...and it seems that, except for three cluster composed by few obs (pretty sure are outliers"), the others redistribute getting more obs for each clusters. So now I'm wondering if the standardization of the log of the variables make sense or not. It is a matter of fact that the variables, also in their log form, have different variance, so I was expcting that the standardization would positively affect the algorithm

Comment: A few quick tips about Fastclus: first, the Niter= option has a default of 1 iteration. Set that to a big number, e.g., 100. Next, invoke the 'delete=' option in the Proc statement to weed out fragmented seeds with small Ns, one heuristic is to use a count based on a single digit % of the total sample. Then, juggling the number of input factors can also help reduce noisy cluster solutions, e.g., if you have 7 factors, try using only 5 of them, and so on. >>>

Comment: ctd.  Finally, don't use a fixed MaxN=10. Put Fastclus into a macro loop and run it for MaxN=3 to 30 solutions. Evaluate each solution based on 3 metrics: the frequency distribution of the clusters (e.g., avoid solutions with a single cluster having 40-50%+ obs), the CCC (pick the max value, even if negative) as well as identifying the solution where the pseudo-Rsquare hits an inflection point and begins to flatten out.

Comment: Another option is to drop customers from the analysis who have only zero values for the financial metrics. Once you have found a reasonable solution based on customers with observable behavior and information, you can fit the excluded 'zero value' customers to that solution based on any additional, nonclustering descriptors such as demographics.